# Стоит ли тестировать методы, которые взаимодействуют с приватным полем?

Tags: java, junit

Задача - протестировать метод, который выкидывает ошибку при отсутствии ссылки на приватное поле. Считается ли это плохим подходом - доставать закрытые поля? В данном примере `audioClip` - закрытое поле. Не могу найти правильного решения как протестировать метод `play`, учитывая что уже в самом конструкторе выкидывается исключение другого типа. И, по сути, в методе `play` исключение типа `NullPointerException` никогда не вызовется.

```
private AudioClip audioClip;

public SoundClipBase(String path) {
    if (path == null || path.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("sound clip can't be null or    empty");
    setPath(path);
    audioClip = new AudioClip(getClass().getResource(path).toString());
}

public void play() {
    if (audioClip == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("audioClip is null");
    audioClip.play();
}
```

Comment: Что имено вы хотите тестировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, тестировать поведение закрытых методов/полей считается плохим подходом. Поскольку считается, что закрытые не являются частью интерфейса/контракта И могут быть изменены в будущем.

Исходя из общей логики, потребность в тестировании закрытого означает что наружу не выставлено что-то важное для внешнего приложения/пользователя. Т.е. внешние наблюдают различное поведение некоего метода, но не могут при помощи открытых методов/полей проверить какое именно ожидать.

и... я бы не прятал исключение, если не собираюсь его обрабатывать.

в данном конкретном случае видим пример отложенной ошибки: где-то ведь этот audioClip инициализируется. Вот там и надо проверять предусловия, вот тот метод и надо тестировать. Здесь - умерла-так-умерла, известите об этом вызывающего исключением.

Comment: имхо, ответ не соответствует вопросу! спрашивается от целесообразности тестирования открытого метода (public void play), а вы говорите про закрытые методы/поля.

Answer (score 1):

как вы справедливо заметили, в данном конкретном случае

```
if (audioClip == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("audioClip is null");
```

не выполнится никогда, потому что поле всегда проинициализированно в конструкторе. т.о. этот код надо не тестировать, а просто удалить за ненадобностью (и чтобы не портил статистику покрытия тестов ;) )

в общем случае в юнит тесте иногда необходимо сфабриковать значения закрытых полей. для этого используются моки (о них можно почитать например тут https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/323920/)
если же использование мок-библиотеки кажется нецелeсообразным, можно использовать старую добрую рефлексию:

```
//SoundClipBase soundClipBaseInstance = ...

Field f = SoundClipBase.class.getDeclaredField("audioClip");
f.setAccessible(true); // это делает поле доступным
AudioClip newValue = null;
f.set(soundClipBaseInstance, newValue);
```